# openssl AES encryption adds a blocksize worth of bytes to output

Tags: bash, cryptography, openssl, aes

I'm trying to encrypt with openssl on the console to match output generated by another implementation of AES. All details are known. I'm using AES in 128-bit CBC mode. Weirdly enough, irrespective of the file size, the output will be 16 bytes larger. I think openssl is appending some kind of padding.

In the direction to the other implementation it's not that much of a problem as I can drop the last 16 bytes, but the other way around is as I can't invent the bytes that openssl will probably check for validity.

How do I tell openssl not to do that?

Commandline:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -K <pre-shared key in hex> -in rawfile.bin -out encfile.enc -iv <pre-shared IV in hex>
```

Comment: could it be the IV being included? (in which case they would probably be inserted at the beginning, not the end)

Comment: Not likely. 05 15 be 1d 9a fb 4c 54  a2 03 90 97 3f 58 28 d8 is the hexdump of a 0-byte file being encrypted, which doesn't match the first or last line of a 32-byte file being encrypted with the same IV. I would expect it to match. Doesn't rule out that it's encrypting the IV last, but that would be unworkable. I think it's encrypting a padding of sorts that probably includes the file length. Hard to compare as it's cbc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`openssl enc` has a `-nopad` option. I've not used it, but it sounds relevant.

```
-nopad
    disable standard block padding
```

Comment: Do wish they'd made the docs a bit clearer. I looked in them for a while but after figuring out the commandline I didn't look much further. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah - that works, but only if you have appropriate input sizes (otherwise you get `5539:error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length:evp_enc.c:228:`)

Comment: I'm doing the padding myself so it's always appropriate.

Comment: For PHP users this is the OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING option, for example `openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);`