# AES encryption inconsistency in PHP using the Open SSL library and coding CBC mode from scratch

Tags: php, cryptography, openssl, aes

I suppose I should deal with my first statement first. Is there an inconsistency in the way PHP does AES-128-CBC encryption when you use the Open SSL library?

I am asking this because if you look through [RFC3602](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3602.txt) for AES then you'll find some test vectors in section 4. The first one I tried was:

> Case #1: Encrypting 16 bytes (1 block) using AES-CBC with 128-bit key
>
> Key       : 0x06a9214036b8a15b512e03d534120006
>
> IV        : 0x3dafba429d9eb430b422da802c9fac41
>
> Paintext : "Single block msg"
>
> Cphertext: 0xe353779c1079aeb82708942dbe77181a

Using the open SSL library with the following code:

```
echo bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($str, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
```

You actually get back:

```
e353779c1079aeb82708942dbe77181ab97c825e1c785146542d396941bce55d
```

Now this is all well and good and decrypts back just fine, and the first 32 bytes are the expected cipher text "e353779c1079aeb82708942dbe77181a". However, there appears to be another 32 bytes at the end of the cipher text returned from the Open SSL library. Why is this? This question becomes relevant next.

As part of something I am doing for fun I am trying to implement AES CBC mode encryption sort of from scratch. The code I currently have for doing this is (based on the RFC previously referenced and on CBC diagrams at the ["Block cipher mode of operation" Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29)):

```
public function cbcEncrypt($str, $iv, $key) {
    $bl = 16;
    
    $bs = str_split($str,$bl);
    $pv = null;
    $r = '';
    
    foreach($bs as $b) {
        if($pv === null) $pv = $iv;
        if(strlen($b)<$bl) $b = $this->pkcs7Pad($b, $bl);
        $pv = openssl_encrypt($b^$pv, 'aes-128-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
        $r .= $pv;
    }
    
    return $r;
}
```

At the moment I'm pretty sure this code wont work on strings longer than the current test 16 byte string anyway, however, I ran this code side by side with the Open SSL implementation to compare. The return value from by CBC implementation is:

```
e353779c1079aeb82708942dbe77181a8b1ccc6f8cd525ffe22d6327d891a063
```

When called via:

```
$crypto = new CryptoTools();
$enc = $crypto->cbcEncrypt('Single block msg',hex2bin("3dafba429d9eb430b422da802c9fac41"),hex2bin("06a9214036b8a15b512e03d534120006"));
```

Again, the first 32 bytes are correct, but the second 32 bytes are again added but completely different from the Open SSL implementation of CBC. Any clues as to why?

Also, the Open SSL implementation of ECB mode returns a 32 byte string, which means CBC encrypting strings currently greater than 16 bytes in length the new value of $pv will be 32 bytes in length and then it will be XOR'd against the second plain text block when in reality shouldn't $pv always be 16 bytes in length? Is it usually just accepted that you truncate $pv from 32 to 16 bytes?

Just in case it helps, the pkcs7Pad method in the code above looks like:

```
public function pkcs7Pad($str, $b = 8) {
    if(trim($str) == '') return false;
    if((int)$b < 1)  return false;
    $p = $b - (strlen($str) % $b);
    return $str . str_repeat(chr($p),$p);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Needless to say there's not much documentation on this as people aren't usually stupid enough to try and reinvent the wheel, certainly in PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha! Got it! Thanks to [ntoskrnl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363280/1196954) and [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127087/openssl-aes-encryption-adds-a-blocksize-worth-of-bytes-to-output) I managed to come up with a solution! If you do:

```
echo bin2hex(base64_decode(openssl_encrypt($str, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv)));
```

You will match the test case provided by the RFC! You just need to remember that because you're now not doing OPENSSL_RAW_DATA you will get back a base64 encoded string and so will need to base64 decode it before converting it to hex to match the test case!

TLDR: it was a padding issue, just not an obvious one!

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with padding. The test vectors don't use any padding at all, while the openssl_encrypt function and your function apply PKCS#7 padding.

PKCS#7 padding is specified so that padding is added in all cases. When the plaintext length is a multiple of the block size, a full block of padding is added, which is why the ciphertext is 32 bytes long when the plaintext is 16 bytes.

Can't immediately see anything wrong with your function (though I'm not familiar with PHP), but you could try padding `$str` before splitting it instead of checking whether each block requires padding.

Comment: 99% of the time encryption problems are padding issues :) problem is they're a nightmare to debug its even worse when you're looking at cross platform padding ie: encrypt in php decrpyt in c# which use different padding characters and counters etc (iirc php pads with tab c# pads with space so instead of padding to 7 you pad to 13 or something insane like that)

Comment: This is why it's important to specify all the parameters explicitly and not rely on defaults. Sadly, some implementations only support the default option. In these cases it helps to be familiar with the API; defaults are typically described in the documentation.

Comment: Indeed one of the things that caught me out was that c# required something like a 32 byte key where as php using mcrypt only accepted 30 it was driving me nuts :) I do suspect the OP is going to have a great quantity of grey hair when he's done (or none left at all)  I've fairly sure I've got code for doing exactly what hes attempting but its at home and I'm at work so I can't compare until I get back later tonight

Comment: Actually, my function doesn't apply padding to the test string at all, it only applies the PKCS7 padding if the string length is less than the block size, and both at 16 bytes. Could the open ssl encryption in ECB mode be applying padding? However, this shouldn't be the case as the block size for AES 128 is ALWAYS 128 bits/16 bytes, so no padding should be needed right?

Comment: As said, PKCS#7 specifies that padding is added in ALL cases, even when the plaintext length is a multiple of the block size. If this wasn't the case, padding would be ambiguous – how would you differentiate between a 16-byte message that ends with a 0x01 byte and a 15-byte message that is padded with a 0x01 byte?